# ¿Cómo actualizar desde una sentencia select?

Tags: condiciones, plsql, update, apex

Necesito actualizar el campo STATUS de mi tabla CLIENT_REQUEST_APP
cuando el campo CREDIT = 'Y'  entonces STATUS = 'GATEKEEPER'

Hasta el momento tengo esto pero como integrar el UPDATE

```
DECLARE 
    :P2_CLIENT_ID := l_client_id;
    
    
   BEGIN
       SELECT  CREDIT FROM  CLIENT_REQUEST_APP
       WHERE CLIENT_REQUEST_ID =  l_client_id;
       IF CREDIT = 'Y' THEN  STATUS = 'REQUEST'; ---quiero actualizar el campo status de la tabla CLIENT_REQUEST_APP
       ELSE STATUS = 'GATEKEEPER';
       END IF;
   END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para actualizar un campo en una BBDD SQL debe usarse la instrucción UPDATE así:

```
UPDATE CLIENT_REQUEST_APP SET STATUS = 'GATEKEEPER'
WHERE CLIENT_REQUEST_ID =  l_client_id;
```

Espero te funcione !!